# Not Found: /static/frontend/styles.css (Docker, Django, Nginx)

Tags: django, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am trying out docker for the first time to deploy in production environment I followed some you- tube tutorials but i was successful in containerizing my Django project. but when i run it nothing appears and i get a 404 error saying not found static/fronted/styles.CSS. Please refer to the attached snippet:

error:

```
dlops-portal | Not Found: /static/frontend/styles.css
dlops-portal | Not Found: /static/frontend/runtime.js
dlops-portal | Not Found: /static/frontend/polyfills.js
dlops-portal | Not Found: /static/frontend/main.js
dlops-portal | Not Found: /static/frontend/scripts.js
```

Here is my Docker file:

```
    FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.8-nodejs14-bullseye

    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

    ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
    ENV LANG C.UTF-8

    RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN set -ex && mkdir /app

    WORKDIR /app

    # Copy the requirements file and install dependencies
    COPY d_requirements.txt /app/
    RUN pip install -r d_requirements.txt

    # Copy the application code
    COPY . /app/

    # Create the /opt/ai_sensei_data_source directory and set permissions
    RUN mkdir /opt/ai_sensei_data_source
    WORKDIR /opt
    RUN chmod a+x+w+r ai_sensei_data_source

    # Copy the .env file to /opt/ai_sensei_data_source/
    COPY /.env /opt/ai_sensei_data_source/.env

    # Change back to the frontend directory to install frontend dependencies
    WORKDIR /app/frontend

    # Install frontend dependencies
    RUN npm install -f
    RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
    RUN ng build --configuration production

    

    # Change back to the /app directory as the final working directory
    WORKDIR /app

    # Install additional packages
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install rsync -y
    RUN apt-get install lftp -y
    RUN apt-get install sshpass -y
    RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nano vim


    # Copy entrypoint script
    COPY ./entrypoint.sh /

    # Set entrypoint
    ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]`
```

Docker Compose File:

```
    version: "3"

    services:
      web:
        build: .
        volumes:
          - static:/static
          - /home/data_source:/opt/ai_sensei_data_source/data_source
          - /home/.ssh:/home/.ssh

        container_name: "dlops-portal"
        ports:
          - "9000:8000"
        environment:
          - /opt/ai_sensei_data_source/.env 
        depends_on:
          - db
          - redis
      nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
          - static:/static 
        ports:
          - "9073:80"
        container_name: "nginx-container"
        depends_on:
          - web
      db:
        image: postgres:12
        volumes:
          - /home/postgres_ai_sensei:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
          - /opt/ai_sensei_data_source/.env
          - POSTGRES_USER=pass
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      
        ports:
          - "5434:5432"
        container_name: "myapp-postgres-db"
        depends_on:
          - redis
      redis:
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
          - "6378:6379"
        container_name: "redis-dlops"
        environment:
          - /opt/ai_sensei_data_source/.env
    volumes:
      static:    `
```

my entrypoint.sh file:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    python3 manage.py migrate --no-input
    python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input 
    gunicorn dlops.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 &
    celery multi start worker8 worker9 worker10 worker11 worker12 worker13 worker14 worker15            worker16 worker17 -A dlops -l info &
    celery -A dlops worker -l info
```

Nginx docker file:

```
    `FROM nginx:1.21

    RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/`




nginx conf file:


    upstream dlops {

        server web:8000;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;
    #  server_name
    #  error_log    
    #  error_page

        root /home/kchavan/dlops-portal/static/;

        location /static/{
            alias /static/;
            expires 1d; 
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://dlops;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    }
`
```

my settings.py file:

```
    STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = 'Media/'
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
    media_directory = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Media')
    os.makedirs(media_directory, exist_ok=True)

    ASSETS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/frontend/assets')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
    ]`
```

file path:

```
`  >project
    >backend
      >settings.py
    >frontend
    >nginx
      >dockerfile
      >nginx.conf
    >static
      >frontend
      >mail
    >dockerfile
    >dockercompose
    >entrypoint.sh`
```

I tried copying the static folder from local system to the nginx container while building the images refer to below code:

Docker file:

```
    `# Copy build static files to nginx conf dir & set permissions
    RUN mkdir -p /home/kchavan/Desktop/dlops-portal/static
    RUN cp -r /app/static/* /home/kchavan/Desktop/dlops-portal/static/`
```

But it didn't work out

Comment: `dlops-portal` this is your django container, not nginx. Which means nginx does not work as you expect, it does not handle request for static files at least.

Comment: side note: this is strange `MEDIA_ROOT = 'Media/' && media_directory = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Media')`

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding but can you share the necessary steps to resolve the issue that you pointed out @IvanStarostin

Comment: Not really. Check nginx logs maybe there are some errors, verify that nginx handles at least some urls. `location /static/` looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that my static files were getting stored in a different location after fixing that everything is working as expected.